# FIWARE Cloud - How to migrate VM to another region?

Tags: cloud, fiware

according to FIWARE Lab's latest “Reminders regarding new Terms and Conditions” from 23. April 2015, the node/region “Spain1” will be shut down and any VMs on that node should be migrated to node/region “Spain2”.

As I have a VM running on node/region listed as “Spain” in the FIWARE Lab web frontend, which I assume is meant by “Spain1” from your email, I guess I have to migrate that VM, too.

What is the recommended way of doing that?

Is there any information available on how to do that? I couldn't find any on the website.

Is there some functionality in the web frontend that I haven’t found yet and that does this migration automatically?

Or is there some other way to copy a VM from one node/region to another?

Or do I have to re-create the VM in the other node/region by hand – and then re-install my app and get another public IP for the VM (which I guess I can’t anyway because public IPs seem to be limited to 1 per user) and then update the public IP in all the clients that are connecting to my VM?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now there is no automatic tool to migrate VMs from a node to another.
My suggestion is to send a message to fiware-lab-help@lists.fi-ware.org and explain that you need to move your VMs to Spain2.